# Can users ask for testers?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, policy

A user recently asked the question, https://stackoverflow.com/q/11943363/672118. Is it acceptable to request that people test your program?

Comment: plz test teh codez

Comment: @BenBrocka [I seductively approve this code.](http://twitter.com/CamBrady/status/230452475218518016)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, that's off topic, there's no actual practical problem to be solved, and it's a bit of the open ended / opinion / discussion-y flavour.

A vastly improved version of the question that would include the essential parts of the question in the question's text would *probably* be on topic for [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). I've posted [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11943363/gem-semantic-navigation-what-do-you-think#comment15912243_11943363):

> Hello freeze, this isn't really a suitable question for Stack Overflow, please read the [FAQ] thoroughly for more details. What we could do though is turn this into a request for code review, all you need to do is add the *essential* parts of your code in the question's text and explicitly ask for a review, and remove the discussion-y "Is here someone who use it, or would like to use it?" - we prefer questions to be about specific problems, not open ended discussions. After you do all that, flag the question for moderation attention and ask for it to be moved to Code Review Stack Exchange.

Hopefully OP will respond positively.

Answer (score 3):

That question is Not Constructive in giant flaming orange letters.

It's, first of all, a poll -- is anyone using this thing? -- second, asking for opinions, third, doesn't actually have a problem that needs to be solved, and for a bonus point, is entirely dependent on offsite code that (conceivably) could disappear any moment.